# How to transfer parameter from constructor into slot?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am doing a small exercise with Qt. As I know, slot `save_clicked` brings only type of parameter. So how can I transfer `userid` into slot `save_clicked` in file `MyClass.cpp` for processing below ?

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QString userid, QString lastname, QString firstname, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();

public slots:
    void save_clicked(QString userid);

private:
    Ui::MyClass ui;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString userid, QString lastname, QString firstname, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ...........
    ...........
    connect(ui.save, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(save_clicked(QString)));
}

void MyClass::save_clicked(QString userid)
{
    // process userid here    
}
```

Comment: in your impementation you can just use a function call in the constructor. Instead of connec() call: save_clicked(userid).

Comment: @FreddyKay: How is that supposed to fulfill the OPs wish to have some click event handled?

Comment: OP: Which version of Qt? If qt5, have you read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html ? Also, if your instance of `MyClass` simply stored the `userid` as a member, you could simply use it in `save_clicked`. Not need to "transfer" anything to the slot. Also, why is your `userid`a `QString`? If it's an integral value, use an integral type.

Comment: @thokra: I am using Qt5. I tried your solution, it works. Thanks ! I am focusing on signal and slot, so I forget that. :) Actually userid consists of both digit and character, so it should be QString.

Comment: @htmlamateur: Nice. Do you want a more thorough explanation of how to pass arguments to slots in Qt5 or are you happy with what you got?

Comment: @thokra: well, I am learning Qt, at first Qt is complicated to me, but the more I work with it, the more I like it. So if you master something about this, please share with me, that would be appreciated ! :)

Comment: @htmlamateur: See my answer. HTH.

Comment: For c++ 11 and Qt 5 you can use a lambda: 
connect(ui.save, &QPushButton::clicked,[this, userid]{save_clicked(userid);});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than use signals/slots just use a variable. It's the goal of a class. Add something like :

```
private:

QString userId;
```

And in your constructor add :

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString userid, QString lastname, QString firstname, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    this.userId=userid;

}
```

Like this you can use userId like you want and where you want into your class.

EDIT :

add in your .h

```
private slots:
    void on_saveButton_clicked();
```

and in your .cpp

```
void MyClass::on_saveButton_clicked()
{
    // you can use userId here
}
```

If you use Qt Creator those functions can add automatically in the UI design interface

Comment: -1. This is not an answer to the problem. You're eliminating the handling of the push button's `clicked()` signal, which is clearly not what the OP intended.

Comment: No, his problem is how to pass *userid* to his function. Now he can use the variable in a simple button_clicked() function.

Comment: Oops, my bad - classic case of "not fully read". Actually that "solution" is what I already proposed in the comment. But I think the answer is incomplete.

Comment: I edit my answer and hope it will be more complete like that.

Comment: @LandelinDelcoucq: thank you very much, it works ! :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there have already been suggestions that `userid` doesn't need to be passed to a slot. Declaring it as a member of `MyClass` and simply using it in `MyClass::save_clicked()` will do just fine.

If you still want to know how to handle the case where you need to pass arguments to a slot not provided by the signal, there are mutiple ways to achieve that and they depend on the version of Qt you're using.

In general, the following from the [Qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) holds for Qt5 and Qt4:

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving
>   slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it
>   receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)

Given that fact, you have to either use what the signal provides (or don't - depends on if you need it at all) or get your data somewhere else. A `slot` is just a regular function (a little more constrained in Qt4 but in Qt5, you can basically connect **anything** that's callable to a signal) and in that function, you can get the data you need from anywhere your design permits. The member variable approach is common, but you can also call another member function of any other object, free function or simply compute whatever you need inside the slot.

Note: Handling a signal doesn't necessarily mean you need *any* data - it's common, yes, but you could also do something simple as bring up a `QMessageBox` with some hard-coded text or simply clear some text edit (think something like a button doing `Clear Console`) or execute some external process or what have you.

If you need your slot to actually **receive** data when it is invoked, you have multiple options:

- use everything or a subset of what the signal provides
- use QSignalMapper to establish a mapping with limited control over your slot arguments
- use the, IMHO, superior approach of using a function object that stores what you need, i.e. either a functor you provide directly or as a lambda or a function object returned from `std::bind`

For the latter to work you need `C++11`support , but by now, that shouldn't be a problem.

In your above example, you could do something like this in the most basic approach (**UNTESTED** - Please report compile errors so I can fix the answer):

```
MyClass::MyClass(QString userid, QString lastname, QString firstname, QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
  ...

  connect (
    ui.save, 
    &QPushButton::clicked, 
    std::bind (&MyClass::save_clicked, this, userid)
  );

  ...
}
```

I the above case, when `clicked()` is emitted by `ui.save`, the function call wrapper returned by `std::bind` will be call, which in turn will call `MyClass::save_clicked` on `this` instance of `MyClass` and pass `userid` to `save_clicked()`.

The above is basically what you wanted to achieve initially. However, this is just the tip of the iceberg. You can go much, much further with this and, for instance, bind **anything** you want.

For instance, suppose you connected to another signal provided by your button, `toggled(bool checked)`. If you wanted to receive both the check status as a bool **and** a number of arguments you provide yourself, for instance the `userid`, you can extend the above call to `std::bind` with an appropriate placeholder:

```
connect (
  ui.save, 
  &QPushButton::toggled, 
  std::bind (&MyClass::save_clicked, this, _1, userid /*, ... more args here*/)
);
```

You would now have the following signature for `save_clicked()`:

```
save_clicked(bool, QString);
```

On emission of `toggled(bool)` by `ui.save`, the function call wrapper returned by `std::bind` will then call `MyClass::save_clicked` with both the bool in place of `_1` **and** the `QString` you provided as the 4th argument to `std::bind`.